# Focus form on key down

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube, focus

I'm trying to use the youtube embedded player ( axshockwaveflash) and make a nice program out of it.

Thing is i'm trying to implement a button that'll replay/next/previous the current video.

what I have atm is:

```
 private void btReplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!youtubePlayer.Focus())
        {
            youtubePlayer.Focus();
            SendKeys.Send("0");
        }
        else
        {
            SendKeys.Send("0");
        }
        this.BringToFront();
    }
```

The '0' key press makes the video replay from the start. Only it also makes the form dissappear between other open windows.

As you see i've tried using bringtofront but it won't work.

Any thoughts?

Also if anyone has any experience with this, i also want to play how to enable auto play the next video when using the 'END' key. I know about the autoplay=1 function but it won't seem to work when pressing the END key.

EDIT: Using WinForms btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.BringToFront();
this.TopMost = true;
```

worked for me, silly i didnt think of this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you use winForms or WPF. This snippet is for winforms.
Here I am giving you a static method that forces any given Form to front:

```
    public static void bringWindowToFront(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
    {
        uint foreThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), System.IntPtr.Zero);
        uint appThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
        const uint SW_SHOW = 5;
        if (foreThread != appThread)
        {
            AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, true);
            BringWindowToTop(form.Handle);
            ShowWindow(form.Handle, SW_SHOW);
            AttachThreadInput(foreThread, appThread, false);
        }
        else
        {
            BringWindowToTop(form.Handle);
            ShowWindow(form.Handle, SW_SHOW);
        }
        form.Activate();
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool BringWindowToTop(System.IntPtr hWnd);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern System.IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(System.IntPtr hWnd, System.IntPtr ProcessId);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);
```

Comment: seems a tad much to just bring a form to the front is it not? Also sorry editted the first post to saying im using WinForms

Comment: It's the "most powerful" winforms solution I know of and brings a form to front even under the most adverse conditions. I use it to call a form on a tray icon click. Otherwise the form might be hidden behind the currently active application.